# Common ground after voltage dc-dc converter

Tags: voltage-regulator, signal, ground

I have a 7.4V LiPo battery that I use to power an ESP8266, some relays and a servo. The LiPo battery is split into a 7.4V rail and using a dc-dc voltage converter (LM2596) into a 5V rail. The 7.4V is for the servo(s), the 5V for the remaining components. In order to make sure that the signals from the ESP8266 are relative to the same ground, is there a need to connect the ground of the 7.4V rail (directly from the LiPo) and the ground of the 5V (after going through the LM2596) or do they share the same "floating" ground?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

schematics are usually helpful.

Given that your DC-DC converter is not isolated, there's no way for you to avoid your subcircuits to share their ground, they will be cconnected no matter what. Then, you will be just ok, and don't need any specific additional connection